# Postgresql Skip Row if value is equal to last row

Tags: sql, postgresql

in Postgres 9.1 is it possible to skip row(s) if the value of NAME is equal to the one before f.e. following table

```
ID | NAME | AGE | SEX | CLASS
---------------------------------
1    Paul   17    M     2b
2    Paul   16    M     2b
3    Paul   18    F     2b
4    Lexi   18    M     2b
5    Sarah  16    F     2b
6    Sarah  17    F     2b
```

The result should be:

```
1    Paul   17    M     2b
4    Lexi   18    M     2b
5    Sarah  16    F     2b
```

Thanks for your help,

t book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from (
  select id, 
         name, 
         age, 
         sex, 
         class, 
         lag(name) over (order by id) as prev_name
  from the_table
) as t
where name <> prev_name;
```

alternatively

```
select *
from (
  select id, 
         name, 
         age, 
         sex, 
         class, 
         row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as rn
  from the_table
) as t
where rn = 1;
```

Another option would be to use Postgres' `distinct on` operator:

```
select distinct on (name) 
       id, 
       name,
       age,
       sex,
       class
from the_table
order by name,id
```

but that will return the result ordered by `name` (which is limitation of the `distinct on` operator). If you don't want that you'll need to wrap this again:

```
select *
from (
  select distinct on (name) 
         id, 
         name,
         age,
         sex,
         class
  from the_table
  order by name,id
) t
order by id;
```

Comment: WOW this was fast! I´ll try it…

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID , NAME , AGE , SEX , CLASS
FROM thetable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM thetable nx
    WHERE nx.NAME = t.NAME
    -- AND nx.ID < t.ID -- ANY one before it
    AND nx.ID = t.ID-1  -- THE one before it
    );
```

Comment: I know that, but the op was not very clear in his requirements ("before it"). That why I added the other exclusion clause, and commented it out. BTW: in most cases, EXISTS will be faster than anything else.

Comment: Both working thanks, wildpassers seems a bit faster with 11000 rows! one more stupid question, would you add a where clause for the class (2b) after  AND nx.ID = t.ID-1 AND t.CLASS = "2b" ?

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised that the co-related subquery seems to be faster. It requires two scans on the table (albeit the second one only partially), whereas the solution with the window function only requires a single scan.

Comment: My fault, to long in front of the computer, yours was faster, mixed something. Time for a dog walk, thanks for your help!

Comment: @tBook: I have added another (Postgres specific) solution. In most of the cases `distinct on` is the fastest option, but if you need it sorted by `id` this might not be the case here.

Comment: Well, it is correct, even faster and less complex and, I don't get any points? Cargo-cult programming, I daresay!

Comment: :) okay the distinct on is definitly the speedy gonzales … strange that it gives me the second row as result f.e. 2 | Paul|16|M|2b But it s probably me, mixinig up something.

Comment: Speed depend on the index structure, obviously. Normally one would expect name and id to be covered by usable indexes. Small queries will always us a hashed plan, which will probably favor the `UNIQUE ON`. For queries that outgrow work_mem, EXIST will probably win again.